# When, if ever, could Javascript's "typeof" return an incorrect type?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work my way through someone else's code and am finding some bizarre things.  I found the following code in part of the program:

```
if(typeof func == "function" || (typeof func == "object" && typeof func.document == "undefined"))
{
    func();
}
```

This made no sense to me, as I wasn't sure when such an event could happen?  Could typeof return the wrong type?  Or is it possible for a non-function object to be callable?

The code is a mess so I can't really find an example of where this particular check might succeed.  I should note that the code may be upwards of 10 years old.  The statement I received was that it was required because sometimes, when the code was originally written, a typeof was not returning function as a type.

Also, this check was required because sometimes func would be passed a window object (?) so it was necessary to make sure it wasn't a window object as well.

Comment: it seems possible from the given code that func could be anything

Comment: This looks like a parameter check, to make sure the parameter given is a function before executing it as one. This hasn't much to do with typeof but more with the way the function gets called. The second part could have to do with older versions of IE, which for example gave "object" as result for the `window.alert` function.

Comment: I do understand what the code is actually doing, I think I was more concerned about how or why this could ever succeed if `func` was not actually a function.  I think gpgekko may have nailed it though.  It's entirely possible that this got passed `window.alert` and if older IE didn't recognize that, this would have been necessary.

Comment: `typeof func == "object"` and `func()` will lead to an error

Comment: @metadings: In modern web browsers.  It might not have 10 years ago.  Host objects are weird, and like gpgekko said, IE said `typeof alert === 'object'`, back in the day.

Comment: @RocketHazmat IE's alert is a single weird exception back in old XP days, don't tell that anyone. even XP got IE8 at least

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember: `typeof` is for literals.

```
typeof undefined === "undefined"
typeof 5 === "number"
typeof true === "boolean"
typeof "" === "string"
typeof {} === "object"
typeof [] === "object"
typeof function { } === "function"

// null is a weird exception:
typeof null === "object"
```

`instanceof` distinguishes when something is "of a Function" (notice that where typeof checks against string `"object"` instanceof checks against Function `Object` itself:

```
{} instanceof Object

function {} instanceof Object
function {} instanceof Function

[] instanceof Object
[] instanceof Array
```

As you see, typeof says `=== "function"` and `!== "object"`: this can be misleading, because a function is also an object. This is when instanceof comes into play.

Now, when you write a constructor, the constructed object is also instanceof your function:

```
// the constructor
function Example { }

// the object
var ex = new Example();

typeof Example === "function"
typeof ex === "object"
ex instanceof Object
ex instanceof Example
```

Using prototype you can also extend the chain, where typeof always says object:

```
function DerivedExample { }

DerivedExample.prototype = new Example();
// DerivedExample.prototype.constructor = DerivedExample;

var ex1 = new DerivedExample();

typeof DerivedExample === "function"
typeof ex1 === "object"
ex1 instanceof Object
ex1 instanceof Example
ex1 instanceof DerivedExample
```

So that's all about javaScript `typeof` and also `instanceof`. Hope it clarifies what's happening.

---

Something also good to know (this is not recommended to be used in production code, but i've seen in also in CoffeeScript source afair):

```
typeof new Number(5) === "object"
new Number(5) instanceof Object
new Number(5) instanceof Number

typeof new Boolean("true") === "object"
new Boolean("true") instanceof Object
new Boolean("true") instanceof Boolean

typeof new String("") === "object"
new String("") instanceof Object
new String("") instanceof String
```

---

About functions and the window object:

Every standalone function will be called in context of window.
(Except) when you `"use strict"` "directive", a standalone function will be called with context of undefined.

```
function world() {
    // non-strict: this === window
    // use-strict: this === undefined
}
world();
```

Now when you write a function as a member of an object, the function's context is the object:

```
var hello = {
    world: function () {
        // this === hello
    }
};
hello.world();
```

This is also true for prototype functions, that are called in context of a newly constructed object:

```
function Hello() { }

Hello.prototype.world = function () {
    // this instanceof Hello
    // this will be === ex
};

var ex = new Hello();
ex.world();
```

And at least, you can change the context of any function using `call` and `apply`:

```
var ex = { };

function Example() {
    // (1) non-strict: this === window
    // (1) use-strict: this === undefined
    // (2) this === ex
}

Example(); // (1)
Example.call(ex);  // (2)
Example.apply(ex); // (2)
```

Comment: Hmm.  I am going to leave this as accepted, but I think I need to reword my question.  What I now realize is that the question I meant to ask was "Could any item x, where `typeof x === "object"`, be called as a function as in `x()`.  However, I think I have a better idea of how to express my thoughts here, so that's a huge plus.

I feel like this is implying that, no, this could never happen, and playing around with JSFiddle seems to agree.

Comment: That's what I thought when i wrote the first comment, you can never use a "standard" object like you use a function, this leads to the `"TypeError: ({}) is not a function."` Only a "Function Object" can be used as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example

```
var a = [];
typeof a; // object
Object.prototype.toString.call(a); // [object Array]

var b = {};
typeof b; // object
Object.prototype.toString.call(b); // [object Object]
```

So yes, `typeof` can be pretty confusing sometimes

Comment: How is this confusing? What do you think it should return? And btw `typeof` is a keyword, so using it on a function manner is confusing.

Comment: Updated... In many cases, using `typeof` to do parameter checking is not correct because `[]` is not the same as `{}` and `typeof` return the opposite thing